# Загрузка своей библиотеки в mavenCentral

Tags: android, maven, gradle, repository

По гайдам создаю свой репозиторий (файл с расширение aar), но не могу найти подробный гайд как загрузить его, что бы им мог пользоваться любой желающий, помогите ссылкой на статью(если это
как-то влияет то проект лежит на gitlab)

Comment: Нужен ли вам именно Maven Central? https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-publish-artifacts-on-maven-central-24342fd286cd

Comment: GitLab тоже это умеет: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/

Comment: Ссылка на medium платная, а вот по второй ссылке, если репозиторий приватный это не проблема?

Comment: Что вам мешает сделать отдельный публичный репозиторий только для бинарных публикаций? Medium откройте в incognito window, раз выбрали лимит.

Comment: Извините, вы не помните с помощью какой команды можно публиковать бинарный файл в gradle?

Comment: Читайте документацию по плагину, что используете для публикации. Обычно `gradle publish` для `maven-publish` плагина.

Comment: Я по вашему коменту выше создла отдельный репозиторий и перенес туда файл с расширением .arr,, и что бы опубликовать его мне нужно всего-лишь вызвать gradle publish?

Comment: Тут ведь все написано: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#publish-by-using-gradle